# jQuery: Selecting custom html tags (with specific values)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have an html page which has elements such as the following:

```
<input data-required-by="books magazines stationery">
```

What I'd like to do is select *all* elements in jQuery that have "books" in the 'data-required-by' field. I was hoping something such as the following would work:

```
$("[data-required-by]~='books'")
```

but it brings back "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ='books'"

Admittedly my jQuery isn't particularly advanced, so it's possible I've missed something simple. Any suggestions appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("input[data-required-by~=books]")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[data-required-by^=books]')
```